# Could the Founding Titan free Annie from her hardened cocoon?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Currently, Annie is in a cocoon of the same material that the walls are made of (although a transparent form of it I guess).

Since the Founding Titan could command Titans to harden, could he also command Titan's like Annie, to "soften"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in chapter 124 of the manga, when

> Eren ―having the founding titan powers― lets out a huge roar, which was a command for all hardened titans to break their cocoon and *thus Annie breaks out of her cocoon as well*.

Another way for the cocoon to break was with the help of

> the Jaw Titan, as it has enough jaw power to smash open the cocoon, just like when Eren defeats the War Hammer Titan this way.